# Image being loaded before app main method is called

Tags: ipad

I have an ipad app where I am seeing an image displaying briefly before the app starts (image is part of bundle).

My guess is that this is some wrong wiring of a xib file, but even when I set a breakpoint at the beginning of the main method, the image still appears before this point is reached.

Resetting the simulator does not help, and the scenario occurs on a device too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm is the image named Default.png ?

I just don't see an other explanation for this problem ^^

By the way, I just don't use Interface Builder to avoid this kind of strange problems ^^

Comment: Thank - Yes, I just realized this, that it was the custom launch screen.